# install telegram on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: telegram

After installing Telegram Desktop on Ubuntu 16.04 by these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```

I get this error:

```
$ telegram
telegram: Panic - Unable to find your tty (pts/2) in /var/run/utmp
```

Comment: The repo is obsolete. The latest version it have is *0.9.35* whilst [the actual latest version atm is *0.9.44*](https://desktop.telegram.org/).

Comment: That ppa is fine. Launch telegram in terminal as `/opt/telegram/Telegram`. Yes it is bad that there is no alias or smth.

Answer (score 6):

## Telegram Desktop

Please use either

- https://telegram.org/dl/desktop/linux (64bit) or
- https://telegram.org/dl/desktop/linux32 (32bit)

## Telegram Web

Telegram offers as well a [Webinterface](https://web.telegram.org) and a [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/telegram/clhhggbfdinjmjhajaheehoeibfljjno).

## More

A list of official and unofficial clients can be found [here](https://telegram.org/apps).

## Special-Case: Franz

I am using [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/) myself, as it covers several Messengers (Skype, Whatsapp, Telegram, Slack, FB-Messenger etc) in 1 client.

Comment: Alright, i added some more links in the meantime. Feel free to report back how it worked out.

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy: is it working for you?

Comment: I had forgotten.please let me to check and waiting to reply :)

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if installation works for you. Greetings

Comment: I am checking this now and will report back if this works.